# Ngrx with lazy load modules

Tags: angular, redux, frontend, lazy-loading, ngrx

Let assume in my application I have the following lazy loading modules:

- Login module
- Admin module

**App-routing.module.ts**
`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule), canLoad: [AdminGuard]}]
```

`

In the LoginModule I've created `StoreModule.forFeature('login', fromLogin.authReducer)`.

After successful login program redirects to the **Admin page(Module)**.

And the store dispatching new action:`this.store.dispatch(login({some object}));` 
Everything works fine.

---

**Problem**

When I try to refresh page on the admin module I will lost store from **LoginModule**.

As you can see in the routing module I'm using Guard `canLoad` logic inside guard should change state in the **LoginModule** store but after refresh page I lost it.

---

Works fine and change state in the **LoginModule**:

[image]

---

Doesn't work after refresh page on the **AdminModule** the store is empty:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to place your store management code in the shared module, as it is shared amongst all the lazy loaded feature modules  (if you never used a shared module, you can look at this [link](https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7) for reference). **Note that you'll need to import the shared module in the app module.**

If you are starting now a new project, I will advise you to check out [NGXS](https://github.com/ngxs/store) which is an alternative to NgRX. I have encountered many programmers who decided to migrate their code from NgRX to NGXS, as it eases the complexity of state management.